# Write Element Ref on HTML using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Hey guys I'm trying to output a block of html code on the screen but I can't.

Basically I'm using `@ViewChild('preview', {static: false}) preview: ElementRef;` to get the html code of a specific div.

I'm building a signature generator and I need to output the HTML code on the screen. However, when I try to print that on the screen, I get:

> [object HTMLDivElement]

On the console.log works great thou. What am I missing?

Thanks

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="preview" #preview>
  <p style="margin: 0"><b>{{ name.value }}</b></p>
  <p style="margin: 0">{{ jobtitle.value }}</p>
  <p style="margin: 0" *ngIf="localnumber.value !== ''">Telephone: {{ localnumber.value }} x {{ ext.value }}</p>
  <p style="margin: 0" *ngIf="email.value !== ''">{{ email.value }}</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p style="font-size: 13px; color: #a0a0a0;"><b>CONFIDENTIALITY NOTICE</b></p>
  <p style="font-size: 13px; color: #a0a0a0;">This email contains confidential information intended for a specific individual and purpose. This confidential
    information is protected by law. If you have received this confidential information in error, you are hereby
    notified that any disclosure, duplication, copying, distribution or action taken based on this confidential
    information is strictly prohibited. Please delete your record of this email and notify us immediately. Thank
    you.</p>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('preview', {static: false}) preview: ElementRef;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  htmlCode;

  getCode() {
    console.log(this.preview.nativeElement);
    this.htmlCode = this.preview.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

Comment: Paste your html code as well.

Comment: For sure. I've edited it. Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling the getCode() method?

Comment: I just added a button. Once the user finishes filling the form it will call the getCode()

Comment: I believe you are trying to make a custom directive, where app-root wouldn't be the right selector:
https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: try this console statement, console.log(this.preview.nativeElement.innerHTML);